# How to set line space in between two fo:block?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have two `<fo:block >` like this. I got big line space between these two blocks.

How can I remove that line?

Here is the code :

```
<fo:block line-height="12pt" font-size="10pt"
    space-before.optimum="1.5pt" space-after.optimum="1.5pt"
    keep-together="always">`enter code here`
    <fo:leader leader-length="100%" end-indent="0cm"
        start-indent="0cm" space-after.optimum="0pt" space-before.optimum="0pt"
        rule-thickness="2.0pt" leader-pattern="rule" />
</fo:block>
<if test="message.msg1">
    <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="Times Roman"
        font-size="10pt" space-before.optimum="1.5pt" space-after.optimum="1.5pt"
        linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false"
        text-align="left"
        wrap-option="wrap">
        <message id="msg1" />
    </fo:block>
</if>           
<if test="message.msg2">
    <fo:block line-height="12pt" font-family="Times Roman"
        font-size="10pt" space-before.optimum="1.5pt" space-after.optimum="1.5pt"
        linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false"
        text-align="left"
        wrap-option="wrap">
        <message id="msg2" />
    </fo:block>
</if>
```

Comment: You code will never work. There is no such tag in XSL as <if>. Please post a real example of what you are doing.

Comment: <if> tag checks by web service if msg1/msg2 exist on the database then display that message.

Comment: You have the xsl namespace as default in the stylesheet (meaning not xsl:if, but just if)?

Comment: Hi Kevin, you mean I need to have xsl:if instead of if?

Comment: Unless you have some empty namespace declared

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you don't have empty lines at the end of your blocks?  It looks like you should only have 1.5pt between blocks.  If you set `background-color` on the `fo:block`, is the big space because of the blocks?

Comment: To expand on what Tony Graham said, due to the presence of `linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false"` your output could have "empty" lines made of space characters.

Comment: What is the tag <if> doing? If that some special thing?

Comment: I kept these (linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" )properties to get text in exact format of text. for example if I hit enter on text it should break the text from that place,

Comment: It's fine for that to be the effect that you want.  The question is whether preserved line breaks in the text are contributing to the big line space that you see.  Have you tried setting `background-color` just to see if that is the case?